# UTF8 version of WIDESTRING

Tags: delphi

I have a text that I need to store it in a `widestring` variable. But my text is UTF8 and widestring doesn't support UTF8 and converts it to some chinese characters.

so is there any UTF8 version of WIDESTRING?

I always use `UTF8string` but in this case I have to use `WideString`

Comment: Please use one version tag, the version that you are using. I guess you are using a Unicode Delphi. So why use WideString. I suspect you need to read up on the topic. Start with Marco's whitepaper.

Comment: UTF-8 is **8** bits wide, so storing it in the **16** bit `WideString` is unnecessary overkill.

Comment: YOu should specify what version od Delphi you're using. Before D2009 Delphi was very little Unicode aware, AFAIK there UTF8String was just an alias for AnsiString, and there were no codepage support beyond the system one, you need to take care of proper conversions. From 2009 onwards it's code page aware and can take care of most conversions. Moreover WideString is an implemetation of COM BString, and it's not the default UTF-16 string implementation since 2009.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you assign a `UTF8String` variable to a `WideString` variable, the compiler automatically inserts instructions to decode the string (in Delphi 2009 and later). It coverts UTF-8 to UTF-16, which is what `WideString` holds. If your `WideString` variable holds Chinese characters, then that's because your UTF-8-encoded string holds UTF-8-encoded Chinese characters.

If you want your string `ws` to hold 16-bit versions of the bytes in your `UTF8String` `s`, then you can by-pass the automatic conversion with some type-casting:

```
var
  ws: WideString;
  i: Integer;
  c: AnsiChar;

SetLength(ws, Length(s));
for i := 1 to Length(s) do begin
  c := s[i];
  ws[i] := WideChar(Ord(c));
end;
```

---

If you're using Delphi 2009 or later (which includes the XE series), then you should consider using `UnicodeString` instead of `WideString`. The former is a native Delphi type, whereas the latter is more of a wrapper for the Windows `BSTR` type. Both types exhibit the automatic conversion behavior when assigning to and from `AnsiString` derivatives like `UTF8String`, though, so they type you use doesn't affect this answer.

---

In earlier Delphi versions, the compiler would attempt to decode the string using the system code page (which is never UTF-8). To make it decode the string properly, call `Utf8Decode`:

```
ws := Utf8Decode(s);
```